# Pytorch modifying intermediate values during forward

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

If I have a model with several different layers, is there a way for me to modify the values in between those layers and see what the result would be if that modified value was passed through the rest of the network? I know you can use hooks to obtain the intermediate values during a forward pass but I would also like to modify them and send them through the rest of the network. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `forward` function you can do what you want, for example:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
    
        # example layers
        self.dense1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.dense2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.dense3 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.dense4 = nn.Linear(128)
        self.dense5 = nn.Linear(128, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dense1(x)
        
        # do what you want with x, for example...

        # ... print the shape
        print(x.shape)
        
        # ... do any modification to x, ie. adding random numbers
        x = x + torch.tensor(512, 1)
        
        x = dense2(x)

        x = dense3(x)

        # loop through x for whatevery reason
        for e in x:
            # do smth with e
            pass
        
        # apply activation
        x = F.relu(x)

        # and so on and so on
```

(The model above makes not really sense but its for demonstration)
As you can see, in forward you can do (almost) whatevery you want between the layers

Comment: I mean for pretrained network. If you trained this on some dataset and saved it and gave me the PTH file, how could I add 5 to the output of the second layer and see what the result is? What if I don't know the model definition?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? @crizal